# Send php form to 2 locations

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, zoho

What is the best/easiest way to send information from a form to two different locations, basically have 2 actions on one form. I have a few fields that need to be named differently for each action, for example..

```
<form id="form" name="form" action='post.php' method='POST' accept-charset='UTF-8'><input type='hidden' name='xnQsjsdp' value=SlGqwqH3ITc$/>  <input type='hidden' name='xmIwtLD' value=x4LHs39QfKiFkCs1PrsnsG-*B6-MHnNR/>  <input type='hidden' name='actionType' value=TGVhZHM=/> <input type='hidden' name='returnURL' />
<input name='firstName' type='text' id="firstName" style="float:left; width:45%;" maxlength='40' />
<input name='lastName' type='text' id="lastName" style="float:left; width:45%;" maxlength='40' />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

post.php look like this.

```
<?php

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {

      $hidden1      = $_POST["xnQsjsdp"];
      $hidden2      = $_POST["xmIwtLD"];
      $hidden3      = $_POST["actionType"];
      $hidden4      = $_POST["returnURL"];
      $firstName    = $_POST["firstName"];
      $lastName     = $_POST["lastName"];
      $street       = $_POST["Street"];
      $city         = $_POST["City"];
      $State        = $_POST["State"];
      $zipCode      = $_POST["Zip"];
      $email        = $_POST["Email"];
      $phone        = $_POST["Phone"];
      $LEADCF7      = $_POST["LEADCF7"];
      $zohoPrams    = "xnQsjsdp=$hidden1&xmIwtLD=$hidden2&actionType=$hidden3&returnURL=$hidden4&First Name=$firstName&Last Name=$lastName";
      $maxPrams     = "FName=$firstName&LName=$lastName";

    };

?>
```

```
<script>
$(function() { // setup an onReady (similar to onLoad) handler
        $.post("https://crm.zoho.com/crm/WebToLeadForm", <?php echo $zohoPrams; ?>; // post to first address
        $.post("http://www.max360group.com/", <?php echo $maxPrams; ?>; // post to second address
});
</script>
```

as you can see i tried using ajax.. but i guess i'm doing something wrong, if you have any suggestions to do this any other way that would be great :] Thank you!

Comment: The first thing I notice is that your `$.post` calls don't have a closing `)` on them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it server side with cURL in post.php.

So, you have your variables set and they've been validated and cleaned, then:

```
$zoho = curl_init("https://crm.zoho.com/crm/WebToLeadForm");
curl_setopt($zoho, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); //Note, not very secure.  Would have to get certificate otherwise.  Look up how to.
curl_setopt($zoho, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); //Makes sure that it follows any redirects
curl_setopt($zoho, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); //Returns the result instead of outputting it to the browser
curl_setopt($zoho, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)"); //Will make the end server think it was submitted with Firefox, and not by a server using cURL.
curl_setopt($zoho, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($zoho, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $zohoprams);  
//If you want the rest of the $_POST data and not just what you set above in $zohoprams, 
//CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS takes either an array, which will automatically do the appropriate thing with it as a $key=$value, or a string like you have formatted for $zohoprams
curl_exec($zoho);
curl_close($zoho);

$max = curl_init('http://www.max360group.com/');
curl_setopt($max, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($max, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $maxprams);
curl_setopt($max, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($max, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($max, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)"); 
curl_exec($max);
curl_close($max);
```

Might need to be changed a bit to do exactly what you want, and probably would need to forge the headers like it's a browser doing it, but that is the basic functionality of it.  Might also need to set CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER to true.

Comment: do i only need the "CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER" line once at the to for the zoho line? or would i need another one for the max?

Comment: That's only for https connections, which zoho is and max isn't.  Basically, what that does is tell it to accept any certificate given, rather than actually verifying that it's a proper certificate for that domain.  If you don't either do that or actually verify the certificate, it will give an error more than likely.  Verifying the certificate is more secure, but more complex, so I just did that, and you can look up how to actually verify a cert.

Answer (score 2):

sending XHR or Ajax requests is not permitted cross domain.  You can achieve this using cURL.  i would imagine there are quite a few tutorials about submitting forms using PHP and cURL floating around here.

sample google search to get you in the right direction: http://www.google.com/search?q=using+curl+to+submit+form+data+php

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that javascript can't be used to access files on other servers like you're trying to do.  An approach that would work would be to have PHP files on your server that just set up forms and post them (via forms `submit()`ted with javascript) to the remote servers.